# scrollIntoView doen't work in IOS - javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad

I have created custom datepicker for mobile device using javascript, when it is clicked am setting the **selected dates to the middle of the viewport** using scrollIntoView function, for the **first time** when it is clicked **it works fine**, but in ***IOS*** the ***selected dates are shown on the top*** and it is not visible in the viewport.

This is working fine in the Android device.

```
scrollToTargetAdjusted: function(calendar_elmnt) {
    calendar_elmnt.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'center'
    });
}


var calendar_elmnt = document.querySelector(classValue);

scrollToTargetAdjusted(calendar_elmnt);
```

Actual in IOS (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjRGS.jpg)
Expected like Android (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY3s0.jpg)

Comment: scrollIntoViewOptions [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Safari doesnt support `scrollIntoViewOptions`

Comment: @AswinKumar any alternate solution you recommend?

Comment: Try this polyfill http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/

Comment: @AswinKumar as am using scrollIntoView not scrollIntoViewOptions in the code and i can see that scrollIntoView is supported by safari 5 for iso from the above provided url

Comment: `behavior` and `block` are the `scrollIntoViewOptions`. Read the docs carefully

Comment: @AswinKumar ok, i got it, thanks.